# What are the allowed group names for groupadd?

Tags: linux, users, group, useradd

I followed [these instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/shadow.html) to build Shadow, which provides the **`groupadd`** command. I am now getting an error when trying this:

```
$ groupadd automake1.10
groupadd: 'automake1.10' is not a valid group name
```

I checked alphanumeric names, and they work okay.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the source code, specifically `libmisc/chkname.c`. Shadow is pretty conservative: names must match the regexp `[_a-z][-0-9_a-z]*\$?` and may be at most `GROUP_NAME_MAX_LENGTH` characters long (configure option, default 16; user names can usually go up to 32 characters, subject to compile-time determination).

Debian relaxes the check a lot. As of squeeze, anything but whitespace and `:` is allowed. See [bug #264879](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=264879) and [bug #377844](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=377844).

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_426) requires allowing letters of either case, digits and `._-` ([like in file names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276)). POSIX doesn't set any restriction if you don't care about portability. A number of recommended restrictions come from usage:

- Colons, newlines and nulls are right out; you just can't use them in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`.
- An name consisting solely of digits is a bad idea — `chown` and `chgrp` are supposed to treat a digit sequence as a name if it's in the user/group database, but other applications may treat any number as a numerical id.
- An initial `-` or a `.` in a user name is strongly not recommended, because many applications expect to be able to pass `$user.$group` to an external utility (e.g. `chown $user.$group /path/to/file`)¹. A `.` in a group name should cause less trouble, but I'd still recommend against it.
- `/` is likely to cause trouble too, because some programs expect to be able to use user names in file names.
- Any character that the shell would expand is probably risky.
- Non-ASCII characters should be ok if you don't care about sharing with systems that may use different encodings.

¹ <sub>All modern implementations expect `chown $user:$group`, but support `chown $user.$group` for backward compatibility, and there are too many applications out there that pass a dot to remove that compatibility support.</sub>

Comment: Re `chown` argument: the current syntax, at least in GNU coreutils, is `user:group`, with dot being accepted only for compatibility. One can use `j.smith:j.smith`.

Comment: @grawity: It's not just GNU coreutils, but the problem isn't `chown` itself, it's existing scripts and other programs that call `chown $user.$group` instead of `chown $user:$group` — even if the `chown` implementation tries to do the right thing, some cases are intrinsically ambiguous.

Comment: "but other applications may treat any number as a numerical id" – True. My friend struggled with `usermod -a -G …`, the tool kept claiming the group did not exist. The provided argument was a name being a number, indeed interpreted as an id. The error was a good thing, it could be worse: if a group with this exact id existed, the command would happily add the user to the "wrong" (i.e. unintended) group and this could be a major security breach.

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling adventurous, you can edit `/etc/group` directly and put in whatever group name you like.  Also, this has the added bonus that when you encounter one of the problems @Gilles mentioned, you may not be able to load an editor to fix the problem, or even log in at all - giving you valuable experience in recovering a broken system!

Comment: Don't forget to edit `/etc/gshadow` when adding groups. Also, use `vigr(8)` rather than directly editing the files.

Comment: Where available, use ```grpunconv``` and ```grpconv``` to unconvert and re-convert the group file. Similarly, use ```pwunconv``` and ```pwconv``` for the password file. These commands remove and re-create the shadow files so that direct editing of the ```/etc/group``` and ```/etc/passwd``` files can be done. When editing, also consider using the ```vigr``` and ```vipw``` utilities, if available.

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone exploring this question more recently:

@gilles-so-stop-being-evil is correct, the authoritative source is `https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/libmisc/chkname.c`, specifically the `is_valid_name` function, but the regex in that file has changed since the original answer was posted: It is now

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,30}[a-zA-Z0-9_.$-]?
```

*with one caveat enforced in the code*, that being that all-numeric names are forbidden. Length checking is enforced by `is_valid_group_name`, which calls `is_valid_name` IFF the length-check passes (likewise for `useradd`, via `is_valid_user_name`).

Comment: Are those `[a-z]` locale dependant? As in does that  include `éᴬᴭᴮɯɰ` on locales that have such characters like `grep '[a-z]'` report or is that only the ASCII ones. Why exclude the letters of other scripts? Is Linux only meant to be used by American English users?

Comment: That is an excellent question: I just checked the source, and it is literally using character comparison against ranges, e.g., c => 'a' && c <= 'z', etc., which looks like ASCII only, but I am not an expert in this area. This does surprise, I admit. I wonder to what extent platform/distro maintainers replace this function...?